# Unable to open sites through domain names in squid proxy server

Tags: squid

How to open sites through domain names in proxy server? I have already declared ACL in the squid config file. Please suggest me where do I have to declare ACL: before or after the ACL Safe Ports?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the allow rule before the deny ACL.

Comment: @JovinThariyath Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend expanding this answer (by editing) to explain this in greater detail, perhaps with an example.

Comment: But in your environment web filtering can be takes place through squidguard and we need to use wildcards like .ae ,.com instead of adding one by one sites manually